# i have an application in which The manifest file contains references to Visual Studio 2008 run time,but i want to compile it in VS2010 express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, x86

i have an application(VC++) in which The manifest file contains references to Visual Studio 2008 run time,but i want to compile it in VS2010 express.what changes should be done in manifest file,although i have all libraries compiled for VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the project file you should be able to open it in VS2010 and the project will offer to upgrade itself for you.

If not, you can probably 'Make a New Project from Existing Code' in VS2010 and wind up with the right manifest. I don't think VS2010 Express Edition has support for this, though.

I'd be wary about manual manifest edits, as it's not clear to me what else might be needed in VS2010 vs VS2008.

Comment: sir now i am using the VS2010(full),does it has support for winding the correct manifest??if yes,then how to wind it up??

Comment: Do you have the project file (.vcproj) for the VS2008 executable? if so just open it in VS2010, it should migrate all the correct things including the manifest.  'wind up' just means how things turn out in the end.